# Find the position of a string in an array of string with the GLib

Tags: arrays, string, glib

I have an array of string, like:

```
char **strings = {"str1", "str2"};
```

And i would like to know if there is a function in the glib to find the position of a string in this array.

I guess i could just do g_strcmp0 in a for() loop, but there may be a better way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function you want does not exist, so you'll have to do it in a for-loop. If you used a `GList` instead of an array, then you could use `g_list_index()`.